# Определение адреса подсети по маске подсети и IP адресу хоста

Tags: сеть, ip, mask

У меня есть IP адрес хоста: 103.252.14.144 / 28.
Используя этот адрес, мне нужно найти адрес подсети, адрес хоста. Рассчитать максимальное количество хостов в подсети, адрес первого хоста, адрес последнего хоста и броадкаст.
Учитывая то, что маска подсети /28 => 11111111.11111111.11111111.11110000 ==> 255.255.255. 240 я понял, что максимальное количество хостов в данной подсети: 14 (2^4 - 2).
Но как я могу определить адрес самой подсети.
Это не может быть 103.252.14.0, так как 103.252.14.144 точно не входит в этот диапазон, учитывая то, что максимальное количество хостов равно 14. Уже имея адрес подсети я могу определить адрес первого хоста, адрес последнего хоста и броадкаст. Каким образом имея данный адрес хоста и маску подсети можно определить адрес подсети?

Answer (score 1):

адрес подсети как раз 103.252.14.144 (то есть "самый первый", его можно определить, наложив маску). Первый адрес 103.252.14.145, последний 103.252.14.158, широковещательный 103.252.14.159.

Как определить этот самый "адрес сети"? смотрим на /28. значит последние 4 бита (32-28) - определяют внутренности сети. Заменяем их на нули - адрес подсети, заменяем на единички - бродкаст.